# How can someone improve bad questions?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, post-ban

Getting banned on SO is very fearful, I feel lucky-seeing how many people get banned<sup>*</sup>- that I'm not *yet* banned.

[image: ban]

Now, even though I'm not banned, that doesn't mean that I don't have low quality questions that I want to improve. But the problem is that there isn't any help on how can somebody improve his questions, the only help you get is:

> Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts! As noted above, down-votes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled, formatted, and overly long or short? Then fix them!

and of course there are articles about how to ask. But I'm interested in how to improve specific questions that are off topic or downvoted.

if a question is off topic and has answers should I change the whole question to make it on topic? (take this question as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296947/how-to-make-a-game-on-play-store, but please don't downvote) 
I wanted to add the example to note how that a question might be so far from the guidlines of the site and can not be edited to make it on topic except if you are going to change the whole question.

Another point is when a question is downvoted or is a duplicate then it doesn't show any research effort. The problem with such questions is that they get answered quickly. What am I supposed to do in this case: it has an answer and iif I did some research I can find the answers; in this case the question will be useless and I can't do anything to improve it. Should I update the question with the answers I find?

Comment: See [Jon Skeet's](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) guide on writing the perfect question.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I read that too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How to fix your question is documented in its entirety at

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

If you have suggestions about how we can make this resource more visible, make it more likely that new users will read and follow it, and ways in which it can be improved for clarity, they are certainly welcome.

Comment: I read this, but it is helpful only for new questions. How can somebody improve current questions if they already have answers.

Comment: Why would the guidelines be any different for already-existing questions?

Comment: that's why I added an example. If you want to make it satisfy the guidlines you will have to change the whole question.

Comment: I don't think you should try to fix questions that are lost causes.  Work on asking new good questions instead.  Good questions offset bad questions for banning purposes.

Comment: I'm not asking only for myself. Banned users are expected to improve such questions and I want to know how.

Comment: The best way is to not get banned in the first place.

Comment: I know I will try that but I'm just pointing to how can already banned users improve such questions. I'm not seeking help to improve my own questions. Imagine that someone who is banned asked this what would be the reply?

Comment: The reply would be **See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997**

Comment: @neomhmd Banned users aren't *expected* to improve.  The fact that they were banned means that we *expect* that they're simply not capable of being acceptable members of the community and so we don't want them here.  If they are willing to make the considerable effort to show that they really are capable of being valuable members, despite our expectations and compelling evidence to the contrary, they are given the opportunity to try to improve.  The *expectation* is that anyone who is a valuable member of the community will never be post banned.

Comment: @Servy and then why does this question exist:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997 to give them false hope?

Comment: To give us something to point to when users post "HALP! IZ BANNED, HOW FIX?"

Comment: @neomhmd It is merely an informational post.  People want to know why they were banned.  This explains why.  For those rare exceptional cases where someone is capable of being a valuable member, but simply hasn't bothered to try up until that point, they can read the information, follow the advice, and work to get unbanned.  Most tend to not try.

Comment: @Servy I'm just saying that you can't stop bad people from entering the site and if this was the reason behind the question ban then it is useless because it wouldn't improve the quality of the site as anyone can make an infinite number of accounts.

Comment: @neomhmd Post bans are deeper than just at the account level.  Creating new accounts doesn't necessarily get a user around the ban.

Comment: @neomhmd You're assuming that SE doesn't have counter-measures for multiple account spammers?

Comment: @Servy and why is that?

Comment: @neomhmd So that people who have been banned stay banned.  I would have thought that goes without saying.

Comment: @Servy no I meant * Creating new accounts doesn't necessarily get a user around the ban* how is this possible?

Comment: @neomhmd There are a number of possible mechanisms, none foolproof, of course, hence the qualifications.  I can't know for sure what all of them are, although I can make educated guesses.  I'm not really interested in helping people subvert them though, so I'll just leave it at saying that they exist.

Comment: In case we haven't made it clear yet, we don't think there's much hope for these folks.  We believe that they are better served by posting to any one of a number of readily available resources *elsewhere on the Internet.*  Folks who have a nominal level of respect for and working understanding of the user community at Stack Overflow don't have to worry about getting banned.  Those who lack this ability seldom reform enough to be productive here.

Comment: And to add to Robert's last comment, most that *do* have the capacity to reform have reformed before they get post banned, after just one or two problematic posts.  It is when users continue to fail to improve that they tend to reach the threshold for a post ban.

Comment: ok thanks I'll make sure I will never get to that point.(I have to admit that this was shocking after all.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not to mention that sufficiently advanced incompetence is indistinguishable from malice. Sometimes I really can't tell if a bad user is so clueless that s(he) can't possibly learn. Or if the user is a troll. The trolls will never reform, because their goal is to be malicious.

Answer (score 4):

The question you linked is just a bad fit for StackOverflow. I don't see any way how you can improve that question. Questions should address specific programming questions you encountered, and not ask for advice how to start a project. I personally would have closed it with the "too broad" close reason, because there are too many answers that could potentially be good, and no obvious choice as to what the best answer should be. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262345/give-user-customization-choice) is probably off-topic too, but I don't see a reason to vote to close half a year afterwards.

You can improve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736022/how-to-change-font-color-in-an-input) by listing what exactly doesn't work. *"but it doesn't do anything."* is a bad problem description. List what exactly you did, even trivial steps (e.g. I pasted code in x, added the url to y like this, and then loaded resource z but I saw nothing happen on the screen), that resulted in this behaviour. What have you tested that might help the question along (e.g. you looked if a script is actually loaded). This will not only make it easier for other people to answer the question, but it will also make it easier for other people that find your question via google to relate to your question.

---

The best way to prevent getting such a ban is by making sure all questions you ask from now on is by making sure your questions are of high quality. Read the help pages. There is even [a checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) that can help you making a good question.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I wanted to know if it is possible to improve such questions. I guess it is not possible.